# windows server 2008 instance on KVM stuck in 'Pause' mode

Tags: windows-server-2008, kvm-virtualization, virt-manager

I have a windows Server 2008 instance as a guest on KVM. When I tried to run it via virtual machine manager, the process got frozen after few seconds and trying to resume the process lead to this error from virt-manager:------

> Error unpausing domain: internal error unable to execute QEMU command 'cont': Resetting the Virtual Machine is required

I tried to Reboot it without any success. Any help will be highly appreciated.

**Edit 1**:

/var/log/libvirt/qemu/vm2.log

> KVM: entry failed, hardware error 0x80000021
>
> If you're running a guest on an Intel machine without unrestricted mode
> support, the failure can be most likely due to the guest entering an invalid
> state for Intel VT. For example, the guest maybe running in big real mode
> which is not supported on less recent Intel processors.

Comment: What Linux distribution and kernel version?

Comment: Linux simah 3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Release: 12.04
Codename: precise

Comment: Edit your question and add in the relevant portion of the log files, which you can find in the `/var/log/libvirt/qemu` directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Congratulations, you've run into [a kernel bug](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.emulators.kvm.devel/91786).

While Ubuntu is shipping a [fixed kernel for 12.10](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1045027), the fix has never been backported to 12.04 LTS. (And while reading the bug on launchpad, I could not figure out how to mark Precise as affected...)

Comment: Thanks for the information.  Is there any fix available for 12.04?

Comment: I already said there wasn't.

Answer (score 1):

your problem happened to me then I try to solve it and I found that happened because KVM memory that I allowed to used from my computer and changed thee "ram from 512 MB allowed to 1024 MB allowed".

You can open virtual manager (`virt-manager`) and edit your physical KVM resource.

Answer (score -1):

if you have intel metherboard, your problem related with that this motherboard have not SLIC-table in BIOS.
maybe this links can help

http://uzlec.ru/vshivaem-tablicy-slic-v-linux-kvmqemubochs.html

http://code.coreboot.org/p/seabios/downloads/32/

Comment: This doesn't appear to have any relevance to this problem.